# Initial Github Repository Commit For Unity Project, One Filename Too Long

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

I've created a new, currently empty Unity project (Unity version 2021.3.15f1) and have created a Github repository for it. I was having trouble with the initial commit--it kept throwing an error at me--so I tried following this guide https://unityatscale.com/unity-version-control-guide/how-to-setup-unity-project-on-github/ to see if I was doing anything specifically wrong. When I got to step 7/step 8, I got another error, so I decided to actually look through to see what was wrong. Almost every file threw up "LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it", except for one:

error: open("ProjectName/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnControllerColliderHitMessageListener.cs.meta"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file 'ProjectName/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8/Runtime/VisualScripting.Core/Events/MessageListeners/MonoBehaviourMessageListeners/UnityOnControllerColliderHitMessageListener.cs.meta'
fatal: adding files failed

Once I unchecked that file from the commit, everything else committed just fine. This is the only file/change that won't commit. My question has a few parts.

1. Do I need to commit this file?
2. If I do need to commit this file, what happens if I don't?
3. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you should not commit this file. The whole `Library` folder isn't supposed to go into the repository, because it's generated by Unity.

What you need to do is:
Add a `.gitignore` file to your repository and commit it (as a single file). From then on git will ignore the `Library` folder and a lot of other things. It will keep working with git much cleaner.

There are templates specifically for Unity, like here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore

How `.gitignore` works is explained here (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: When I created the repository on Github's website, there was an option to add a .gitignore, which I did and selected the Unity template. There's a .gitignore text document file in the repository, in the same folder the .git folder and the Unity project folder are in. Does "the root of your Unity project directory" refer to the repository folder, where the project folder is located, or within the project folder itself? And will moving the .gitignore into the project folder and committing only that change let the .gitignore function properly?

Comment: Yes - moving the `.gitignore` generated from github to the `ProjectName` folder should work as well. We're doing the same in our project.

Comment: That's all it took, thanks!

Comment: Have in mind that the paths in `.gitignore` are always relativ to the folder it is placed in ... so yes if you have e.g. `Library/` as ignore pattern it needs to be placed within the Unity project root folder .. otherwise you would need to add the folder and do `RootFolder/Library/` etc